# Sharing variable data from one widget to another dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `StatefulWidget` post_view that creates a `DataTable`. The data used to fill up the `DataTable` is from a static method in another class named Post:

`

```
static  generateData(){

  List<Post> postList= [];

  postList.add(Post(title: "Coolest Post", numDownVotes: 6, numUpVotes: 9));
  postList.add(Post(title: "Covid-19 vaccine found!", numDownVotes: 3, numUpVotes: 67));
  postList.add(Post(title: "Unreal ending to basketball game", numDownVotes: 2, numUpVotes: 23));
  postList.add(Post(title: "Sample Post", numDownVotes: 2, numUpVotes: 6));
  postList.add(Post(title: "What A Save!", numDownVotes: 5, numUpVotes: 34));


  return postList;
}
```

`

I have the `DataCells` in the table such that the number of up/down votes are in a row widget within the data cell along with an icon button to change or increase/decrease the number of up/down votes respectively. So, I have a variable '_posts' declared inside post_view that calls `generateData()` and displays the data, but I want to be able to manipulate this data and pass it to another widget `BarGraph`, which will generate a bar chart of the dynamic data.

Here's my `BarGraph` widget:

`

```
class BarGraph extends StatefulWidget {
  BarGraph({Key? key, required this.tableData}) : super(key: key);

  List<Post>? tableData;
  @override
  State<BarGraph> createState() => _BarGraphState();
}
```

`

The issue here is that `TabelData` is not accessible at all but I want to be able to get the titles, numupvotes, and numdownvotes to be able to display them in a chart. I tried using a getter but the null check operator doesn't work with that. I'm completely stuck, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can either lift your state up or use a state management package

Reference

- [Lifting your state up](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/lifting-state-up-and-callbacks-7a19d0bdbe53#:%7E:text=In%20flutter%20we%20have%20this,is%20similar%20to%20the%20concept)
- [Lifting state up](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

State Management Package

- [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get)
- [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod)
- and more...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured it out! Just using 'widget.tableData' was enough haha

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! By using `widget.tableData` I was able to access the data passed on to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

What about using any state management approaches such as: Bloc, Provider, etc. Using these libraries can solve your problem as well as make your code more organized. For example, using bloc will look like

```
class ManagePost extends Cubit<List<Post>> {
  List<Post> postList = [];
  void addPost(Post post) {
    postList.add(Post);
    emit(postList);
  }

  void deletePost() {}
  void updateVote() {}
  void getAllPost() {}
}
```

Next, wrap your view in BlocBuilder, it will listen to state of post list and update UI.